# Stems of my areca palm are gone brown and no new stems are coming out of it. How can I save my plant?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, palm

[image]

I keep it indoor in semi bright space and water in after 2-3 days.

Comment: Does the pot have a drainage  hole? How long have you had the plant?

Comment: Yes there's a hole. I have it from 2 years

Comment: I can see two green stems - is there a leaf on top of each one? Actualy a picture showing the whole plant would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Soil looks kind of muddy to me. They tend to prefer well-draining, sandy type soil. Have you ever repotted it? If not, after two years it may be time.